# Sorting numbers and text properly with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am putting together a list of names. But when I sort the list the numbers don't sort the way I want them to.

Here's the pertinent section of the XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="index">
<index><xsl:for-each select="indexitem">
<xsl:sort select="translate(name, '&lt;&quot;', '')"/>
<xsl:sort select="searchscott" data-type="number"/>
<indexitem>
<xsl:apply-templates select="name"></xsl:apply-templates> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="scott"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="searchscott"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="searchterm"/>
</indexitem></xsl:for-each></index>
</xsl:template>
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<index xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><indexitem>
<name>3-Leaf Clover Snowflake</name>
<scott>(4102)</scott>
<searchscott>4102</searchscott>
<searchterm>3-Leaf Clover Snowflake</searchterm></indexitem>
<indexitem>
<name>2004 Olympic Games Athens</name>
<scott>(3863)</scott>
<searchscott>3863</searchscott>
<searchterm>2004 Olympic Games Athens</searchterm>
</indexitem>
<indexitem>
<name>1943, Turning The Tide</name>
<scott>(2765-)</scott>
<searchscott>2765-</searchscott>
<searchterm>1943: Turning The Tide</searchterm>
</indexitem>
<indexitem>
<name>50s Sporty Cars</name>
<scott>(3931-3935)</scott>
<searchscott>3931-3935</searchscott>
<searchterm>50s Sporty Cars</searchterm>
</indexitem>
<indexitem>
<name>&lt;Valley of the Yosemite&gt;, by Albert Bierstadt</name>
<scott>(4346)</scott>
<searchscott>4346</searchscott>
<searchterm>Albert Bierstadt, Valley of the Yosemite</searchterm>
</indexitem>
<indexitem>
<name>13 - Star Flag over Independence Hall</name>
<scott>(1622)</scott>
<searchscott>1622</searchscott>
<searchterm>13 - Star Flag over Independence Hall</searchterm>
</indexitem>
<indexitem>
<name>1606 Voyage of Samuel de Champlain</name>
<scott>(4073)</scott>
<searchscott>4073</searchscott>
<searchterm>1606 Voyage of Samuel de Champlain</searchterm>
</indexitem>
<indexitem>
<name>Racing Car 1911</name>
<scott>(2262)</scott>
<searchscott>2262</searchscott>
<searchterm>17.Racing Car 1911</searchterm>
</indexitem>
<indexitem>
<name>Duryea, 1893</name>
<scott>(3019)</scott>
<searchscott>3019</searchscott>
<searchterm>1893 Duryea</searchterm>
</indexitem>
</index>
```

Am I dreaming to think I can get the smaller numbers to sort first? Such as:

```
<name>3-Leaf Clover Snowflake</name>
<name>13 - Star Flag over Independence Hall</name>
<name>50s Sporty Cars</name>
<name>1606 Voyage of Samuel de Champlain</name>
<name>2004 Olympic Games Athens</name>
```

Or, is this just impossible?

Thanks

Comment: I'd consider that 'dreaming' to expect it to work the way you want without effort :) You might be able to separate leading number part from the letters using regex in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: I can use 1 or 2. But most of the routines we're using are based on 1.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following adjustment using `substring-before()` and `translate()` attempting to slice the name by the space after the numbers. This is the best I can do. Try editing document or software output of xml in removing hyphens (i.e., `3-Leaf`) and joining letters like in (i.e., `50s`).

Also, do note the processor still considers it a string sorted as such and not be numeric value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

<xsl:template match="index">
  <index>
    <xsl:for-each select="indexitem">
      <xsl:sort select="substring-before(translate(name, '-', ' '), ' ')"/>

      <xsl:copy-of select="." />

    </xsl:for-each>
  </index>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```